# Solving first order ODE: $(4x+3y^2)+(2xy)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve this ODE:
$$(4x+3y^2)+(2xy)\frac{dy}{dx}=0.$$

I am having trouble doing this ODE.
I tried using separable of variables and integrating factor and I am having no luck.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= -\frac{2}{y}-\frac{3y}{2x}$$

Comment: It should be :$\frac{dy}{dx}= -\frac{2}{y}\color{red} -\frac{3y}{2x}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= -\frac{2}{y}+\frac{3y}{2x}$$
This is Bernoulli 's Differential equation. Multiplu by $2y$:
$$2yy'= -4+\frac{3y^2}{x}$$
$$(y^2)'= -4+\frac{3y^2}{x}$$
Substitute $z=y^2$ then it's a first linear DE.
$$z'= -4+\frac{3z}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

In the equation $(4x+3y^2)+(2xy)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, you can see $y^2$ and $2y \frac{dy}{dx}$, so the Substitution  $u=y^2$ would be helpful :

$u=y^2 $ then $u'=2y \frac{dy}{dx}$ :

$$(4x+3u)+x u'=0$$
$$u'+ \frac{3}{x} u=-4$$

Now solve the equation and then substitute back.

Comment: I tried your method and i got $(y^2 x^3) +x^4 =C$.. However the sample answer is saying $y^2 x^2 +\frac{4x^3}{3}=C$. Have i made a mistake somewhere

Comment: @BlueCross00 your answer is correct( to check that you can take a differential of your answer) . are you sure the sample answer said $y^2 x^2 +\frac{4x^3}{3}=C$ ?